# Angularjs form json submision

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Trying to make a call to github which requires JSON post requests only.

Trying to get my form on my angularjs application to submit via JSON.

I have this so far:

```
<form ng-submit="postComment(issue.issue.number)" enctype='application/json'>

    <textarea name="body" id="" cols="30" rows="5" ng-model="$parent.issueComment" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.postComment = (issueNumber) ->

            repo.postComment(issueNumber, $scope.issueComment).then (issue) ->
                console.log issue
```

Service:

```
postComment: (issueNumber, body) ->
            console.log body
            # body = JSON.stringify({body: body})
            console.log body
            $rootScope.githubToken.post("/repos/#{@owner}/#{@name}/issues/#{issueNumber}/comments", {
                data: {
                    body: body,
                    hi: "hello"
                },
                dataType: "json"
            }).done (response) ->
                console.log response
```

I keep getting error:

`message: "Problems parsing JSON"`

**FIXED**

```
postComment: (issueNumber, body) ->

            $rootScope.githubToken.post("/repos/#{@owner}/#{@name}/issues/#{issueNumber}/comments", {
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "body": "#{body}"
                }),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType:'application/json'
            }).done (response) ->
                console.log response
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your post like

```
 .post("/repos/#{@owner}/#{@name}/issues/#{issueNumber}/comments", {
     data: {
         body: body,
         hi: "hello"
     },
     dataType: "json"
  })
```

Try with

```
.post("/repos/#{@owner}/#{@name}/issues/#{issueNumber}/comments", {     
      body: body,
      hi: "hello"  
 })
```

EDIT---------------
And trying to stringify your object?

```
var obj = {     
      body: body,
      hi: "hello"  
 };
 obj = stringify(obj);
.post("/repos/#{@owner}/#{@name}/issues/#{issueNumber}/comments", obj)
```